# Always get two push notifications per reply

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When ever someone replies to a comment or question I always get two push notifications from this app

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPhone7,1
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot? Sure it's not two comments on same post?

Comment: See the screenshot I just added above

Comment: Hmm. Do you happen to have both the beta and the stable versions installed?

Comment: No, just done a search to be doubly sure only have one app, only installed this a week or two ago from the App Store

Comment: One last idea, do you have several logins, that you use in the same time? For example both by Google and Stack Exchange OpenID

Comment: I did start out years ago with an open id, but am using Google now. Didn't think I'd used my open id recently though.

Comment: Weird. Guess only a dev can shed more light on this then. :/

Comment: Does logging out and back in fix it?

Comment: Send me another reply please

Comment: Pinging 1 2 3 4

Comment: Still get 2 notifications

Comment: How about now @Jules?

Comment: I think that's ok, but I had my phone unlocked can you try again ?

Comment: Testing again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by Dalgas.

Whenever the app launches, it requests a new push token from Apple and stores it on our server, updating the record matching (accountID, deviceID) with the new deviceToken.  Somehow you had multiple valid records for your one device and were thus getting pinged twice.

Comment: No way to tell how those multiple records were created, to prevent such things from happening to others?